# Update row based on values of the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'm trying to do a really simple update of a row with a request like this one:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
SET LINE_TX = 1000/(SELECT AMOUNT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE LINE_ID = 1 AND LINE_ORDER = 2)
WHERE LINE_ID = 1 AND LINE_ORDER = 2;
```

Is there a way to do it with only **one where clause** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reference the column:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
    SET LINE_TX = 1000 / AMOUNT
    WHERE LINE_ID = 1 AND LINE_ORDER = 2;
```